# Finding HTML after Selenium actions on a website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Have a look at this website- https://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t146sb05 . 
Enter the value 6150 in the text box and press Enter.
See that the url does not change, but the HTML changes. I want to scrape the values 117,129 and -13.57% from this page. I have entered the value and pressed Enter using Selenium, but don't know how to proceed further.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
from lxml import html
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

DRIVER_PATH = 'E:/Anaconda3/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t146sb05')

input_entering = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="co_id"]').click()
new_driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="co_id"]').send_keys(6150, Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to perform action on object which not valid click & send_keys attribute.

Please try below solution ::

```
driver.get('https://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t146sb05')
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="co_id"]')
element.send_keys("6150",Keys.RETURN)
```